How to search for a attribute substring for a xpath when the attribute is not known?
I have a xpath like
//*[name()='svg' and contains(@data-type,'CHASSIS')]

This will lead to below html
<svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" version="1.1" id="asr9901-front_coreLayer_2" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 1663 329" xml:space="preserve" width="1674px" height="325px" sodipodi:docname="asr9901-front_core.svg" inkscape:version="0.92.1 r15371" data-orientation="undefined" data-moduleId="271730511" data-type="CHASSIS">

Basically I want to search for the string "NCS-4202" and "Front" without specifying any attribute.
How can I do the search ?
I tried with
//*[name()='svg' and contains(@data-type,'CHASSIS') and contains(., 'Front')]

but had no luck. It failed to search for any xpaths.

Can you share the HTML as text rather than an image?

It's not clear from your description where the strings "NCS-4202" and "Front" are expected to appear. In any attribute of the element? In any text node child? In any text node descendant? In any attribute of any descendant?

Note also that the test name()='svg' is very unsafe because the result of name() depends on the choice of namespace prefixes. Use local-name() in preference.

See the duplicate links to refine your understanding in three key areas: (1) How to write an XPath that tests attribute values independent of attribute names; (2) How to write an XPath that tests against namespaced XML; (3) What exactly contains() means in XPath.
